# how to manage TFS builds from Jenkins/Maven

Tags: maven, tfs, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

In order to build a cross integration-platform, i need to be able to manage TFS builds from Jenkins and/or Maven, for .NET project we use TFS 2013 as scheduler not only source control and one of the requirement is to keep it for microsoft technologies

So the purpose is to be able to monitor multi-technologies projects in one integration plateforme

we have this architecture : 
[Git and TFS as source control,

a Jenkins master, and 2 slaves (one under OSx for iOS mobile projects, one under Linux for Java projects, and another one under windows for .NET projects)

...
+
and all kind of testing tools as Sonar/Ndepend/Karma, ....

]

But as we have to keep TFS as scheduler for .NET projects (for reasons of maturity Users), 
as principale scheduler with some slaves per domain, the Jenkins Slave under (windows) should be able to request TFS to run builds with their different steps, and also get back the results, the status of each builds, ... ect

My Questions is : how can we do that, is the jenkins plugin for TFS able to meet these needs ? (Jenkins Team Foundation Server Plugin)

Can Maven do this through maven-release-plugin ?

Thanks for your returns

br

Comment: You can use the Jenkins TFS plugin to checkout sources, make a label in TFS after a build etc. but i'm not sure if you get it to run it in maven-release-plugin,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better creating your builds in TFS and running only maven on the Linux boxes. You can do this by having the workflow use Putty to call stuff on Linux. There is some [guidance from the rangers](http://www.scribd.com/doc/90785100/Rangers-Build-Customization-Guidance) however my customer just setup a custom scenario in only a few days. No Jenkins, all TFS->TF Build-> Maven.